# How can I create a regression of x versus y?

Tags: c++, math, linear-regression

I read three vectors from a csv file: x, y_low, y_high. x is the independent time series variable. y_low and y_high are the low and high observations of the dependent variable.

I want to write a function that will take these three inputs as arguments and use an algorithm to find linear regression x versus y.

I basically want the slope and intercept of the correlation. I am not sure how to approach this question as I am not given a y series to read from the dataset. Is it possible to estimate y from the given dataset and get a series of estimates?

I also need an error function as below:

1) if the estimate is between low and high, error is 0

2)if the estimate y is above y_high, error is y-y_high

3)if the estimate y is less than y_low, error is y_low-y

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is it possible to estimate y from the given dataset and get a series of estimates?

Yes. The difficulty is there are *multiple ways* of estimating your ys. The simplest would to take the midpoint of y_low, y_high.

Comment: I made an addition to my question regarding the error function. If I were to follow the estimation way you mentioned, I would get a 0 error function, is that correct?

Comment: @Doe not neccecarily. A *linear* regression is just a single line, you may still have lows above or highs below it